# When I Install ghost with ghost-cli I get this error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, blogs, ghost-blog

I have ubuntu 20.
I installed Ghost according to documentation https://ghost.org/docs/install/ubuntu/ , but when I run `ghost install`
I get this error

```
✔ Checking system Node.js version - found v14.18.3
✔ Checking logged in user
✔ Checking current folder permissions
System checks failed with message: 'Missing package(s): Nginx
Some features of Ghost-CLI may not work without additional configuration.
For local installs, we recommend using `ghost install local` instead.
? Continue anyway? (y/N)
```

Comment: Hi - this seems to not be a programming problem, but a software use problem and would be better on superuser.com, or a related site. With that said, you don't have nginx installed, which is one of the prerequisites of installing ghost. a `sudo apt-get install nginx` should get you past that particular error, but it might just push you to another problem.

Comment: i have installed it before installing ghost.

Comment: Is nginx *running*? i.e. `systemctl status nginx` should show it's running. If it's not running you will see this error